# ls sort files by type in columns

Tags: shell, ls

I would like to sort files by type and display them in columns. I know how to sort by type:

```
ls -X
foo.py bar.py foo.txt bar.txt foo.png bar.png
```

but how to get this?

```
foo.py  foo.txt  foo.png
bar.py  bar.txt  bar.png
```

Comment: `ls -X` is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by command

```
ls -X | pr -3 -t
```

Test Result

```
bash-4.3$ ls -X                                                                                                   
bar.png  foo.png  bar.py  foo.py  bar.txt  foo.txt                                                                
bash-4.3$ ls -X | pr -3 -t                                                                                        
bar.png                 bar.py                  bar.txt                                                           
foo.png                 foo.py                  foo.txt
```

**Hope this Helps!!!....**

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for any content, for instance a folder containing 6 `.png`, 4 `.py` and 2 `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu=( $PWD/* )
for m in ${menu[@]}
do
    echo  "$(basename $m)"
done |xargs -L3 |column -t
```